# WCF Data Services 2 tables insert conflict

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services

I am trying to connect 2 tables with WCF DataServices.
I've tried AddLink method with no success.

Example:

```
        public Vehicle AddVehicle(VehicleModel data, List<Car> cars)
    {
        var vehicle =
            Vehicle.CreateVehicle(
                0,
                data.VehicleType
                data.CreatedBy
                );

        this.ClientRepositories
            .DBContext
            .AddToVehicles(vehicle);

        this.AddCar(cars, vehicle);

        this.ClientRepositories
            .DBContext
            .SaveChanges();

        return vehicle;
    }

    public void AddCar(List<Car> cars, Vehicle vehicle)
    {
        foreach (var item in cars)
        {
            var car =
                Car.CreateCar(
                    0,
                    vehicle.Id,
                    false
                );

            this.ClientRepositories
                .DBContext
                .AddToCars(car);

            this.ClientRepositories
                .DBContext
                .AddLink(vehicle, "Cars", car);

            // Add the new order detail to the collection, and 
            // set the reference to the product.
            vehicle.Cars.Add(car);
            car.Vehicle = vehicle;
        }
    }
```

I am getting the error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Car_Vehicle". The conflict occurred in database "DBTest", table "dbo.Vehicles", column 'Id'.

I was following this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.addlink%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Well, still- taht has nothing to do with SCF and all with basic - really basic - database. YOu can not insert a row that violates the FK constraint.

Comment: SCF? Can you please elaborate what are you trying to say? I am using WCF Data-Services to insert into DB, therefore I have to use AddLink, but I am not sure where I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Vehicle AddVehicle(VehicleModel vehicle, IEnumerable<Car> cars)
{
    using(var context = this.ClientRepositories.DBContext)
    {
        context.Vehicles.Add(new Vehicle()
        {
        Type = vehicle.VehicleType,
        CreatedBy = vehicle.CreatedBy
        };

    foreach(var c in cars)
    {
        context.Cars.Add(new Car()
        {
            SomeBool = false,
            Vehicle = vehicle
        };
    }

    context.SaveChanges()
    }
}
```

Models should then look like this:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public Vehicle()
    {
        this.Cars = new List<Car>();
    }

    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Type {get;set;}
    public string CreatedBy {get;set;}
    public List<Car> Cars {get;set;}
}

public class Car
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public bool SomeBool {get;set;}
    public Vehicle Vehicle {get;set;}
}
```

And turn on auto increment for Id's, or implement your own logic for that. Could use Guids for example.